# View week of the calendar in Excel

Tags: excel, calendar, display, dayofweek

I want to create a calendar in Excel with 2 sheets:

1. Actual monthly calendar
2. Display current week of the month AND cells displaying data accordingly

**Task**: I want to show the people who are working this week rather than the whole month.

I got the code for current week display:

```
=TEXT(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3),"mmmm dd, yyyy")&" - "&TEXT(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)+6,"mmmm dd, yyyy")
```

So, this will show the current eeek starting on Monday and ending on Sunday (as I needed to display)

Now:

1. On sheet 2, I want to show ONLY the dates of week on the calendar based on this above calculation.
2. Match the week start date to a list of Mondays in a different tab, then display the name of the person on the cells below the matching date (this is VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP)
3. Have this automatically updated every week with correct info

Is it possible? How?

I am not a coder at all.

Answer (score 0):

In a blank sheet (**Sheet2**):

A2 `=TODAY()`
A4 `delta`
A5 to A19 `consecutive values from -7 to 7`
B4 `Today+delta`
C4 `Weeknum`
D4 `Weekday`
E4 `Key`
F4 `Today+delta (again)`
B5 `=$A$2+A5` and then replicate this formula until B19
C5 `=WEEKNUM(B5)`
D5 `=WEEKDAY(B5)`
E5 `=CONCATENATE(C5,"-",D5)`
F5 `=B5`
Now extend those formulas (B5:F5) until row 19 (B19:F19)

In another blank sheet (**Sheet1**)
In the firs row put your formula
A2 to G2 `consecutive values from 1 to 7`
A3 `=CONCATENATE(WEEKNUM(TODAY()),"-",A2)`
Extend that formula in the range A3:G3
A4 to G4 `Weekday names from Monday to Sunday`
A5 `=VLOOKUP(A$3, Sheet2!$E$5:$F$19, 2, 0)`
Extend that formula in the range A5:G5

Until now, you should have Sheet1 with the requirement of the week showing every day of the current week. If you need a different week, just change the value in Sheet2!A2 adding or substracting days.